# How can I compile(gcc) on my c file at Cgreen?

Tags: unit-testing, gcc, cygwin, cunit

I should use Cgreen to do work related verification.
I get help here and I success build Cgreen from 'make' command.

---

- make
- make test
- make install

---

but my question is how to compile as gcc compiler for the .c file I created.
If anyone is familiar with Cgreen, can you explain to me with an example?

error message is

---

$ gcc first_test.o -lcgreen -o first_test

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcgreen
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

---

Comment: Add Cgreen as a tag. Without it you will just annoy the folks that can help you with cygwin but have no clue about Cgreen. You will need to show more information about how you (successfully) compile, link, and execute your .c file.

Comment: i'd liked to add Cgreen as a tag but can't use Cgreen tag here.

Comment: Do a search for Cgreen and see what tags other people have used with their Cgreen questions.

Comment: is `/usr/local/lib/libcgreen.dll.a` installed ? Have you tried with also `-L/usr/local/lib` ?